# Sending message with CAPL and dbc signal values

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I am using CAPL to simulate a test envirmonet for some small tests and i am having problems sending messages or more specific setting up the values.

I am able to read Signal Values with $SignalName, also i am able to set signal values like that.

If i am using this code to send a message the message data is always 0:

```
on key 't'
{
  message MessageName msg;
  setSignal(SignalName,i);
  write("Value: %d",i);
  outport(msg);
}
```

Witch makes kinda sence becouse i think the message objects are intended to be used to send bytes witch you can access through msg.byte()

I know that i can set signals in messages by msg.SignalName, but again this seems not the right way. I think there should be a way to send a message and all the signals contained in the message are set to the values set by SetSignal() function. Otherwise the SetSignal Funktion is a bit useless

Maybe somebody has an idea.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am using CANalyzer version 8.2 and I do not have the option to use SetSignal(signal, value) function. Setting the signal values by accessing the message selectors seems to be a reasonable approach. However you used the function outport! You need to use the output function to transmit messages.

```
on key 't' {
  message MessageName msg;
  msg.signal1 = value1;
  output(msg);
}
```

For this method the database has to be configured so that the message msg contains all the necessary signals (signal1).

If you want to set all signal values to the start values configured in the database use the function:

```
setSignalStartValues(message msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an interaction layer that will handle the messages as defined in the CAN database (DBC file) assigned to the node. The interaction layer will need some attributes in the database to define how the messages have to be sent. If not already present you may have to add these attributes. If the Tx messages are not sent as expected, check the attributes.

Function output() is useful if you want to implement (and fully control) the sending of the message yourself.

Instead of using SetSignal() it is also possible to write the signal using    `$SignalName = value;`

See this support note:

https://kb.vector.com/upload_551/file/SN-IND-1-011_InteractionLayer(1).pdf

You may have to guess and experiment a bit. In the DBC files provided by a customer I found attribute values that are not mentioned in this document.